# What's the best virtualization software to install multiple OS?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualization

I'm using Windows XP on my PC. I'm trying to install Ubuntu.

I want these two OS on my PC running simultaneously. How can I do that, e.g. switching between different operating systems while running another OS?

Comment: Just try some virtualization software like VirtualBox and report back if you have a real problem please.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need virtualization software to install two OS's... You'll just follow the instructions given by Ubuntu:

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation
```

Ubuntu's installation will repartition your hard drive, and allow you to choose which OS you'd like to boot into when you start your PC.

As far as actual virtualization software is concerned, Oracle's Virtualbox is very easy to use and get started with. I suggest trying that if you don't want to actually repartition and install Ubuntu.

```
https://www.virtualbox.org/
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) both on Mac and Linux and I'm pretty happy with it